# NSAttributedString adding a custom attribute loses html tags

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Lets say i have a string from a web-service that returns basic html. I want to insert this into a UITextView with a custom font, but after setting it i lost the  tags for example.

```
let htmlString = "<b>This is a title</b><br/>Another line."

let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? Data(),
        options: [
            .documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding : String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ],
        documentAttributes: nil
    )
```

This renders "ok" despite the fact that the font is super small and not my font. After setting an attribute...

```
let attributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: Fonts.raleway(ofSize: 17) ]
attributedString?.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString?.string.count ?? 0))
```

I lost the bold.

Any ideas?

Comment: Being bold or not is part of the font. Since you replace every font reference in the attributed string with a new, single font, any bold is gone.

Comment: So how should i mantain the tags changing the font type and font siZe?